# Updating Sorted Set with Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, redis

Currently I am trying to update a sorted set member.  Looking at the docs, using `ZADD` appears that it should update a member if its score already exists.  However, upon using this code to try to update a member,

```
db.zadd("users", parseInt(key, 10) + 1, JSON.stringify(newData));
```

....a new entry is added even if a score already exists!  How to I update a sorted set member with redis?

Answer (score 8):

ZADD will replace an old member's score so long as the key and member match between entries:

```
redis localhost:6379> ZADD test-key 40 blah
(integer) 1
redis localhost:6379> ZRANGE test-key 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "blah"
2) "40"
redis localhost:6379> ZADD test-key 45 blah
(integer) 0
redis localhost:6379> ZRANGE test-key 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "blah"
2) "45"
```

Perhaps you're using different keys or members between ZADD commands?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to update the existing member(value) of a score(numeric identifier).  I have discovered with some testing that the only way to do this is delete the old record and reupload a new version of it.  Blah, I would love redis to add the ability for updating a member if the score is the same!

Comment: A sorted set can hold multiple members with the same score. You can update a member with a new score, but it doesn't make sense to update a score with a new member as it would be unclear what to remove. 

If you simply wish to add a new member with a given score and delete all current members with that score, you can write a Lua script for this.
If you elaborate more on your use case I can give you a better answer.

Comment: When I found my record, I was just saving its data into JSON and then deleting it.  After updating my JSON object, I reuploaded it with the same score.

Comment: how will you replace blah with different value?

Answer (score 6):

@Eli already explained how to update element score and now **zadd** added new options which is explained by @ZettaCircl and I'm explaining **how to update element with examples using score and element**.

1. NX = add new element
2. XX = update element

**Add three countries into sorted set**

```
 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd country nx 1 'pakistan' // nx = add new element
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd country nx 2 'turkey'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd country nx 3 'UK'
(integer) 1
```

**Get country with scores**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange country 0 10 withscores
1) "pakistan"
2) "1"
3) "turkey"
4) "2"
5) "UK"
6) "3"
```

**Update country**

Update country Pakistan (element) to new name **using score**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd country xx ch 1 'islamic republic of pakistan'
(integer) 0 // 0 means not updated
```

Update country score of Pakistan using **element name** ('pakistan')

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd country xx ch 4 'pakistan'
(integer) 1 // updated successfully
```

**Get country with scores**

We can see here we updated the score only.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange country 0 10 withscores
1) "turkey"
2) "2"
3) "UK"
4) "3"
5) "pakistan"
6) "4" // score updated
```

**Conclusion**

We can update only score in sorted sets using element name.

---

**How we can update elements**

First we need to remove country paksitan.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrem country pakistan
(integer) 1 // removed successfully
```

**Get countries with scores**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange country 0 10 withscores
1) "turkey"
2) "2"
3) "UK"
4) "3"
```

**Add Pakistan with new name**

Add new element into country sorted set with new name and previous score

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd country nx 1 'islamic republic of pakistan'
(integer) 1
```

**Get countries with scores**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange country 0 10 withscores
1) "islamic republic of pakistan"
2) "1"
3) "turkey"
4) "2"
5) "UK"
6) "3"
```

**Conclusion**

First we need to delete element then add new element into sorted set.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the documentation changed since your 2013 answer.

```
ZADD options (Redis 3.0.2 or greater)
ZADD supports a list of options, specified after the name of the key and before the first score argument. Options are:

XX: Only update elements that already exist. Never add elements.
NX: Don't update already existing elements. Always add new elements.
CH: Modify the return value from the number of new elements added, to the total number of elements changed (CH is an abbreviation of changed). Changed elements are new elements added and elements already existing for which the score was updated. So elements specified in the command line having the same score as they had in the past are not counted. Note: normally the return value of ZADD only counts the number of new elements added.
INCR: When this option is specified ZADD acts like ZINCRBY. Only one score-element pair can be specified in this mode.
```

From https://redis.io/commands/zadd

So now, you can tell what behavior you are expected from ZADD. Given your answer, the option XX would do the work.
So something like :

```
db.zadd("users", XX, parseInt(key, 10) + 1, JSON.stringify(newData));
```